# get return value from sql request

Tags: javascript, sql, html, sqlite

I'm currently working on a little app using phonegap and sqllite.
Filling the database works fine; but I need a function which returns me a html-string (for a id).

I have this little snippet from the internet which I "improved" for my purpose, but it doesn't work like expected :(

```
function getPriceFromDatabase(id) {

var result = [];

// Query the database
//
function queryDB(tx) {

    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM PRICEFTS WHERE pid MATCH ' + id, [], querySuccess, errorCB1);

}

// Query the success callback
//
function querySuccess(tx, results) {
    var len = results.rows.length;


    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {     
        result.push('<span class="'+results.rows.item(i).priceart+'">'+results.rows.item(i).price+'</span>');
    }


}

// Transaction error callback
//

function errorCB1(err) {
    console.log("Error SQL: " + err.code);
}


// Transaction success callback
//

var db = window.openDatabase("sucheDB", "1.0", "Suche DB", 52428800);
db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB1);



return result.join('');

}
```

Here is my sample event:

```
$("#price_button").click(function () {

    var p = getPriceFromDatabase(88361);
    console.log(p);
    $('#price').html(p);

})
```

(I get always 'undefined' as result)

can someone help?

thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the on-success callback to the `db.transaction` call, like this:

```
db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB1, querySuccess);
```

Also this function is probably async, so your `return` is executed before the transaction could finish.